# how to get Kafka max offset by producer

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I use command line to get the max offset of one topic. I mean the max offset that is not belonging to any consumer, it's the producer's max offset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kafka provides System Tool [GetOffsetShell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools) to get latest offset of each partition of topic. 

For example consider a topic 'MyTestTopic' with 2 partitions. Then command should be like

`bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell  --broker-list localhost:9092 --partitions 1,0 --topic MyTestTopic --time -1`